# Wcf service Abstract class as Method argument

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I got some wcf service. 
I got also:

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseClass
{

}

[DataContract]
public class ClassA : BaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    //some data members
}

[DataContract]
public class ClassB : BaseClass
{
    [DataMember]
    //some data members
}
```

I got method

```
[OperationContract]

public void SendData(BaseClass[] data);
```

So i need to pass `Array` of `ClassA` and `ClassB` to my service.
How should i mark my classes to make it visible in service metadata, and overall make that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx).